# Bounding a solution of an ODE with a small source

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I have an ODE of the form

$$ f''(x) + f(x) = \epsilon g(x)$$

with initial conditions

$$ f(0) = f'(0) = 0 $$

$g(x)$ is $O(1)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, and $g(x)$ is as smooth as necessary.  Is there a way I can bound $f(x)$?  In particular, I would like to be able to claim that $f(x)$ must be $O(\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ for all $x>0$, but I'm not sure if this is true or how to approach this.  Any hints/advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I also know that $g(0) = g'(0) = 0$, if that helps with anything.

EDIT2: Upon seeing the answers, I think we can see that the values of $g$ and $g'$ at $0$ are irrelevant as long as $g(x) = O(1)$.

Comment: You can solve the ODE by constructing a [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) for it. The end result is
$$f(x) = \epsilon\int_0^x g(z) \sin(x-z)dz$$
and you can use this to bound your $f(x)$.

Comment: ^Awesome, that's consistent with what the two answers said.  And because $g(z) = O(1)$ and $sin < 1$, $f(x) = O(\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation as a system of two linear differential equations. There is a closed form for the solution of such system. In particular, you have to:

1. Find the solutions to the homogeneous problem and stack them in a matrix $X$
2. Compute the particular solution as $X\int X^{-1} \underline{f}(x)$, where $\underline{f}$ is the right hand side in the linear system formulation.

Now, if you can compute the integral, then you have an explicit formula for the solution, and you can find a bound. Otherwise, you need to bound the integral, to find a bound for the solution.

Note: since both the initial conditions are zero, the particular solution is THE solution to your problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, in my particular case, $X$ would be something like $[ \cos x , -\sin x; \sin x, \cos x]$ and your "f(x)" would be $[0; \epsilon g(x)]$?  Then, in step 2, all I would be doing is multiplying $\epsilon g(x)$ by sin's and cos's and integrating from $0$ to $x$, correct?  Then, I will have a particular solution of the form $\epsilon$ times something of $O(1)$.

Comment: Sounds about right.

Answer (score 1):

Put $f_1 = f$, $f_2 = f'$. Then $f_1' = f_2$ and the equation gives $$f_2' = -f_1 + \epsilon g.$$ Thus we have a system $$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \begin{matrix}f_1 \\ f_2 \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix}0 & 1\\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix}f_1 \\ f_2 \end{matrix} \right) + \epsilon \left( \begin{matrix} 0 \\ g \end{matrix} \right), \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,    \left( \begin{matrix}f_1(0) \\ f_2(0) \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix}0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right).$$ You can solve this systems explicitly using an integrating factor (and matrix exponentials) then look for a bound on $f_1$ since $f_1 = f$.